# SystemEvents and resuming from sleep

Tags: .net, session, suspend, systemevent

Imagine I was creating an application that measured how long a certain user is logged in to a computer (the actual application I'm writing is different, but that doesn't matter).

I need to track when the user logs in, logs out, when he suspends the computer (“stand by“ choice in the Shut Down menu) and when the computer resumes from sleep.

I am using [`SystemEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) (specifically, [`PowerModeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx) and [`SessionSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch.aspx) events) for that and it mostly works, with one exception:

When the computer is suspended, the `PowerModeChanged` event is correctly raised with the mode `Suspend`.

When the computer resumes, `PowerModeChanged` is raised with the mode `Resume`. So far so good.

Right after that, `SessionSwitch` event is raised with the reason `SessionLock`. But when I eventually log in after the resume, there is no `SessionUnlock`.

This behavior happens on Windows XP, and I need this to work correctly on XP, Vista and 7.

Is there a way how to receive this unlock?

Comment: No, there's no documented way in Windows to detect a secure desktop becoming inactive.  You have to poll.

Comment: If you mean detecting whether the user is at the computer (and moves the mouse, presses keys), I don't care about that, just whether he is currently logged in, the computer is not suspended and the session is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was an uncaught exception in one of my handlers. Apparently, this stopped subsequent events from firing.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I think it's possible someone might encounter the same problem, so having the answer here could be useful.

Comment: @ian: svick is correct.  This is a useful question which should not be deleted.